# How can I find the following limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to \:4}\frac{\sqrt{x+5}-3}{x-4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

> Find the following limit:$$\lim\limits_{x\to \:4}\frac{\sqrt{x+5}-3}{x-4}$$

I tried to multiply by the conjugate and it did not work.

Comment: It does work. Multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{x+5}+3}{\sqrt{x+5}+3}$. On top we end up with $x-4$.

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply by the conjugate, you should find

$$\frac{(x + 5) - 9}{(x - 4)(\sqrt{x + 5} + 3)} = \frac{x - 4}{(x - 4)\sqrt{x + 5} + 3}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: thanks it worked. I don't know what happened it must be one of those days that my brain decides to not work.

Comment: @Erick Verify your result: you should get: $6^{-1}$ at the end.

Comment: @Aðøbe thank you I got that answer

Answer (score 1):

In case you are familiar with derivatives: this limit is the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{x+5}$ at $x=4$.

Comment: no I'm not familiar with derivatives yet. I will soon be,I'm a first year college student.